# update s3 record based on kafka event

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka

We have records in the s3 bucket (which get updated daily via a job). And We need to listen to a Kafka stream/topic and when a new event arrives in this Kafka stream, we need to update that particular record in s3.
Is this possible?

To my understanding, we need to take the data dump of s3 (via scala code or something) and write to it. IMO, this is not a practical way.
Is there an efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unclear if you meant S3 event or Kafka event.

For S3 write events, you can use a Lambda job to notify some code to run, and Kafka does not need involved. Could be any language - Python or NodeJS seem to be most popular for lambdas.

For Kafka records, your consumer would see the event, then use a S3 client API to do whatever it needs with that data, such as write/update a file. Again, any language can be used that supports Kafka protocol, not only Scala. After which, a Lambda could also read *that S3 event*.

Comment: thank you OneCricketeer - this makes sense.
I have updated my original question: its kafka event. So, once we recieve a kafka event, we can use s3 API to update that particular record in s3? and no need to take the data dump and update?